# Can't extract data from the JSON file

Tags: python, json

I don't understand why I can't print out the data from `label`. After what I've looked up this should do it:

```
import json

json_str = '{mechanisms": {"label": "Mechanismen", "type": "MechSections"}}'

data = json.loads(json_str)

print(data['mechanisms'][0]['label'])
```

Instead of giving me the content from `label` I get an error. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm/Projekte/Vivia_Medikamente/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = json.loads(json_str)
  File "C:\Users\Bennett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Bennett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Bennett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing quote in your json. Also your json doesn't contain list. Following should work:

```
import json

json_str = '{"mechanisms": {"label": "Mechanismen", "type": "MechSections"}}'
data = json.loads(json_str)
print(data['mechanisms']['label'])
```

Output:

```
Mechanismen
```

Answer (score 2):

There are small errors in the code you have provided. Try this:

```
import json

json_str = '{"mechanisms": {"label": "Mechanismen", "type": "MechSections"}}'

data = json.loads(json_str)

print(data['mechanisms']['label'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try just

```
print(data['mechanisms']['label'])
```

also ur json data is bad try this json data instead maybe

```
json_str = '{"mechanisms": {"label": "Mechanismen", "type": "MechSections"}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is a nested dictionary like json

```
json_data = '{
   mechanisms": {
       "label": "Mechanismen", 
       "type": "MechSections"
   }
}'
```

in the case of dictionary or `{}` you should use `key` instead of `index`

like that

```
json_data['parent_key']['child_key']
```

```
json_data['mechanisms']['label']
json_data['mechanisms']['type']
```

In the case of the list, it should look like this

```
{
   mechanisms": [{
       "label": "Mechanismen", 
       "type": "MechSections"
   }]
}
```

Now for this case, as you see there is `[]` before `{}` then you should give the index first then you can access the inner dictionary element by key

In this case,

```
json_data['parent_key'][list_index]['child_key']
```

```py
json_data['mechanisms'][0]['label']
json_data['mechanisms'][0]['type']
```

Now, in your case its works like that

```
import json

json_str = '{mechanisms": {"label": "Mechanismen", "type": "MechSections"}}'

data = json.loads(json_str)

print(data['mechanisms']['label']) 
# As there is no list representation so you can directly access it by giving `child_key`
```